# I can't get my pointLabels to work with my jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a graph with 4 different lines plotted using jqplot. I don't really want to create a legend so I wanted to label each line. I saw that there's a feature called pointLabels however, my labels aren't showing.

```
//function for the line graph
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var yticks = ['Early Definition', 'Pre Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'PV', 'Sprint To Launch'];

        var line1 = [[0, 1, null], [10.4, 2, null], [20.8, 3, null], [31.2, 4, null], [41.6, 5, 'FFD'], [52, 6, null]];
        var line2 = [[0, 1, null], [10.4, 1, null], [20.8, 2, null], [31.2, 3, null], [41.6, 4, 'Customer 1'], [52, 5, null]];
        var line3 = [[0, 1, null], [10.4, 2, null], [20.8, 4, null], [31.2, 5, null], [41.6, 6, 'Customer 1']];
        var line4 = [[0, 1, null], [10.4, 1, null], [20.8, 1, null], [31.2, 1, null], [41.6, 4, 'Customer 1'], [52, 5, null]];

        var plot3 = $.jqplot('linegraph', [line1, line2, line3, line4],
          {
              title: 'All Companies',
              // Series options are specified as an array of objects, one object
              // for each series.
              series: [
                  {
                      // Change our line width and use a diamond shaped marker.
                      lineWidth: 4,
                      markerOptions: { style: 'dimaond' },
                      //color: '#FFFFFF'
                  },
                  {
                      // Don't show a line, just show markers.
                      // Make the markers 7 pixels with an 'x' style
                      lineWidth: 4,
                      markerOptions: { size: 7, style: "x" }
                  },
                  {
                      // Use (open) circlular markers.
                      lineWidth: 4,
                      markerOptions: { style: "filledCircle" }
                  },
                  {
                      // Use a thicker, 5 pixel line and 10 pixel
                      // filled square markers.
                      lineWidth: 4,
                      markerOptions: { style: "filledSquare", size: 10 }
                  },
                  {
                      pointLabels: { show: true, location: 's', ypadding: 3 }
                  },
              ],

              axes: {
                  xaxis: {
                      renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                      label: 'Work Weeks',
                      max: 55,
                      min: 0,
                      tickOptions: {
                          formatString: '%.0f',
                      },
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                      label: 'Phases',
                      renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                      ticks: yticks
                  }
              },
          }
        );

    });
```

I've made sure that I've included the script for the pointLabels too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the point label options outside of the series array and into a `seriesDefaults` section:

```
seriesDefaults: {
    pointLabels: { show: true, location: 's', ypadding: 3 }
}
```

Updated fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/R6sFn/3/

Comment: yes, I see that works really well. However, when I try it outside of jsfiddle I get an error and I'm not able to list a value as null. Do you know what could be causing this. Thanks

Comment: The error I'm getting with this is:  '_elems[...]' is null or not an object

Comment: Not sure what to suggest except also check the External Resources listed in the fiddle and be sure you're loading all the required files in your local project. If the point labels work now but there's a separate issue with nulls, perhaps isolate that code and post in another question.